# Get all opened resource handle in PHP

Tags: php

I have been working with a PHP application, which uses the methods `fopen`and `ftp_connect` a lot. One of the servers where the application is running throw a `Fatal Exception`, when too many files are opened, Hence I needed to find all classes which used that methods and refactored them so that they close the file handles afterwards with `fclose` and `ftp_close`.

By doing this I wanted to add an integration test afterwards which tracks down all opened resources so that something like this would not happen again.

Is there a way to do this in PHP?

Answer (score 3):

You can obtain desired result using [`get_defined_vars()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.get-defined-vars.php), [`gettype()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.gettype.php) and — optionally — [`get_resource_type()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.get-resource-type.php):

```
$resources = array();

foreach( get_defined_vars() as $key => $val )
{
    if( 'resource' == gettype( $val ) )
    {
        $resources[ get_resource_type( $val ) ][] = $key;
    }
}

foreach( $resources as $type => $res )
{
    echo sprintf( '%- 20s: % 3d%s', $type, count($res), PHP_EOL );
}
```

Assuming you have these opened resources:

```
$handle = fopen( '/Your/File/Path' );
$ftp1   = ftp_connect ( 'ftp.site1.com' );
$ftp2   = ftp_connect ( 'ftp.site2.com' );
```

Above code will output:

```
stream              :   1
FTP Buffer          :   2
```

Answer (score 1):

PHP 7.0.0 introduced a function to get resources, called [`get_resources()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.get-resources.php).

Comment: Good hint. Need to try this one of the newer environments.