# Close all the opened files at once in php

Tags: php, file-handling, fclose

Is there any way to close all the files that are open in the program without using fclose() for each file separately?

Something like this-

```
$txt_template1 = fopen("1.txt", "r") or die("Unable to open file!");
$txt_template2 = fopen("2.txt", "r") or die("Unable to open file!");
$txt_template3 = fopen("3.txt", "r") or die("Unable to open file!");
$txt_template4 = fopen("4.txt", "r") or die("Unable to open file!");
$txt_template5 = fopen("5.txt", "r") or die("Unable to open file!");
$txt_template6 = fopen("6.txt", "r") or die("Unable to open file!");

fclose(ALL_OPEN_FILES);
```

Comment: Although I never attempted this myself, but have you tried a `foreach`? Could work. Maybe even with `glob()` but I can't be sure about that.  You could also open all of those files in an array https://stackoverflow.com/a/37780414/ that could lead you to something else.

Comment: They will all close when the script ends, do you need to close them sooner?

Comment: @AbraCadaver Well, I don't explicitly need to, but isn't it a safe practice to close all the open files?

Comment: Watch this answer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35900688/get-all-opened-resource-handle-in-php .

Comment: @FunkFortyNiner Opened the files in an assoc array and closed in a foreach loop. Works fine. But I'm looking if there's a less messy solution.

Comment: Any time you find yourself using variables with names like that, you should probably be using an array. If you had all the open files in an array, you could do `map('fclose', $txt_template)`

Comment: @Replik @Barmar I have files opened at different locations in the code. Some can be opened in an array, some not. Finally i combined both your answers and came to this solution- `array_map('fclose', get_resources('stream'));` This just works in PHP7 but solves my problem. :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`get_resources()` is a function in PHP7 that returns an array of all currently active resources.

For an array of all opened files, use it with the filter 'stream' - `get_resources('stream')`

Map the returned array with the function `fclose()`

`array_map('fclose', get_resources('stream'))`

This will close all the open files.